# running jupyter notebook kernel: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil._psutil_windows'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I start Jupyter notebook and open a file, the file does not stop loading. In the terminal is the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil._psutil_windows'`. At the top of the table bar in Notebook tab there is not the book but the hourglass.
I have tried several things, but nothing helps.

- Path variable reset
- Pycharm reinstalled
- tried new interpreter (not sure if this is really a new interpreter)
- activated venv again

Comment: Is this a notebook running on your own computer, or are you using a Jupyter service somewhere?

Comment: it is on my own computer.

Comment: And did you install `psutil` in your Jupyter session?  That's not a standard package.